# Feed shows only Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

The feed in the Stack Exchange Android app only shows new questions from Stack Overflow.
But my favorites are Game Development, Raspberry Pi, Super User, Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange.

I think it should show all of these in the feed.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ibky Not my kind of cute.

Comment: @CodyGray: I've learned something today again, and wish I could unlearn it...

Comment: There just aren't enough warning signs on the way to Meta.

Comment: Sorry this was just a mistake while typing. I've edited it.